# Aliases tab in portal_types tool in ZMI

Tags: plone, zope, dexterity

I was trying to debug an unrelated issue with my site when I noticed the Aliases tab in the portal_types tool in the ZMI.  I get no response if I try to access it in my Plone 4.1.5 site which uses dexterity.  The following error is logged:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
 Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
 Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
 Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
 Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 322, in __call__
 Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 359, in _bindAndExec
 Module Products.PageTemplates.PageTemplateFile, line 130, in _exec
 Module Products.PageTemplates.PageTemplate, line 79, in pt_render
 Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 126, in pt_render
  - Warning: Compilation failed
  - Warning: exceptions.SyntaxError: invalid syntax (4c47ca874ec06dbf9207ed3a51ff9bb29425ee06.py, line 4)
PTRuntimeError: ['Compilation failed', 'exceptions.SyntaxError: invalid syntax (4c47ca874ec06dbf9207ed3a51ff9bb29425ee06.py, line 4)']
```

It is working for a separate Plone 3.3.6 site I look after.

Is this view still supported in Plone 4.1?

Comment: Looks like you're using chameleon templates. Probably just need to file a bug to get it fixed. There were many template bugs and it seems they're are some still to be fixed with chameleon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As vangeem says this is a Chameleon issue

https://github.com/malthe/chameleon/issues/114